# How to create, update and delete forms in the same template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, crud

I intend to update, create and delete on the same template, as shown below.

I currently have the following on my models

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    TITLE = (
            ('Mr', 'Mr'),
            ('Mrs', 'Mrs'),
            ('Miss', 'Miss'),
            ('Ms', 'Ms'),
            ('Dr', 'Dr'),
            ('Sir', 'Sir'),
            ('Madam', 'Madam'),
            )

    STATUS = (
            ('Active', 'Active'),
            ('On hold', 'On hold'),
            )

    GENDER = (
            ('Male', 'Male'),
            ('Female', 'Female'),
            )

    ROLE = (
            ('Customer', 'Customer'),
            ('Admin', 'Admin'),
            )



    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=TITLE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    country = CountryField()
    birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=GENDER)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='images/default.png')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ROLE)
```

and my forms is as follows

```
class CustomerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [ 'title','first_name','middle_name','last_name','phone','country','birth_year','gender']
```

Currently I have my views showing to update each customer, as shown below.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def CustomerProfile(request, pk):

    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    formie = CustomerProfileForm(instance=customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formie = CustomerProfileForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if formie.is_valid():
            formie.save()
            return redirect('/')


    context = {'formie':formie}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_profile.html', context)
```

In another template i have a list of customers, with each having an edit button directed to each customer update as shown above.

But have separate button called "NEW", which I need to direct to the same template as the update customer, but to create customer.

Is this possible to occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different names for your **Edit** and **New** buttons in your form in template like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="new_customer" value="New" />
    <input type="submit" name="edit_customer" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

and catch them inside your `CustomerProfile` in `views.py` like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'edit_customer' in request.POST:
        formie = CustomerProfileForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if formie.is_valid():
            formie.save()
            return redirect('/')
    elif 'new_customer' in request.POST:
        #  create new customer here

    # your other codes ...
```

Comment: Yes I use two button form in same template in my answer

Comment: I gave it a shot, but doesn't seem to work, would it be better to create a separate function for it?